# change on natbib references

Tags: cross-referencing, natbib

I'm using abbrvnat as my bibliography style, and I wanted to change three things on the way the references are displayed in the bibliography section:

1) Change all of author's name in the reference section to uppercase.

As default I have the following: E. R. Mansell ...

I wanted: E. R. MANSELL ...

2) Change the order that the name is displayed in the references to first appear the name of the author, then his other names separated by a comma.

As default: E. R. Mansell ...

To: MANSELL, E. R.

3) Change the the journal's name from italic to bold

The main reason I'm using this style is because of the citation in-text, which can be displayed like Mansell et at., 2005 or (MANSELL et al., 2005). As far as I know, any other style that has the author name in capital letter can display the in text citations like that.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Regarding "MANSELL": Do you want "regular" uppercase letters, or do you want caps-and-small-caps? And do you want the uppercasing to apply to the names shown in the citation callouts as well, or just to the names shown in the references?

Comment: Preferably regular uppercase letters. The uppercasing could go just to the references. I saw on another post a way to make the citep in text citation to appear in uppercase, so that much is taken care of.

Comment: This is not an answer, since it does not address natbib. But you should look at biblatex. There you can change these things more easily. You get all the functionality you need.

Comment: As long as the text appear the way I want it to, it doesn't really matter which style I'm using. I'll look into the biblatex. Thanks